# Unexpected string error with simplest of queries

Tags: php, sql, select

I'm extremely new to PHP/SQL and I'm trying to write the simplest of queries for a database I've set up, but I can't seem to get it right. I'm using the same exact syntax as I've seen on countless tutorials, but it returns an error no matter what I try.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database_user","database_user_password","tourneys_db");

SELECT * FROM Warhammerk

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

"Warhammerk" is the name of the table in my the database named "tourneys_db". The table consists of 34 columns with 3 rows of data. I have a form set up to execute the above code upon clicking the submit button. The error returned is as follows:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/tourneys/public_html/search40ktournament.php on line 4

(I understand that this sort of query is neither optimal nor secure--I just need to know what the syntactical error is)

Comment: You're using SQL directly in PHP. It's like talking French in a Polish city, of course nobody will understand you.

Comment: Thanks for that completely unhelpful comment.

Comment: You might want to read this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: My point was that you need a translator, an intermediary. The php server doesn't care about anything but php, so you need that translation layer, wrapper ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to take your connection and use it to execute your query.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

For example, try

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database_user","database_user_password","tourneys_db");

$myQuery = "SELECT * FROM Warhammerk";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $myQuery);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

You'll have to figure out what to do with the `$result`, but there are many tutorials about that.  Check out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php